# how to iterate over a particular column of 2D array using range based loops in c++

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I have array `board[n][n]`.What I want is to traverse from `board[0][2]` to `board[n-1][2]` using range based loop `for_each()`.Can it be possible using range-based loop in c++?

Comment: I suppose you must program your own iterator class (which can be templated so that you can use it for all arrays). It will hold a pointer to an element, but the increment operator advances the pointer to the next sub array, i.e. row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my attempt at providing a custom iterator for a two-dimensional array. I named it colIterT, for "column iterator type". The column which the user chooses is a parameter to the iterator constructor. The array dimensions are template parameters (I couldn't figure out how to avoid that nuisance: After all, the dimensions are part of the array type and are perfectly well known to the compiler, so just passing the array type should suffice.)

Note that there is no encapsulation and no bounds checking for brevity.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

const int rows = 5, cols = 3;

template<int rows, int cols, class elT> struct colIterT
{
    // We need this boilerplate code if we want to use
    // <algorithm> with the iterator. 
    using value_type = elT;
    using difference_type = int;
    using pointer = elT*;
    using reference = elT&;
    using iterator_category = forward_iterator_tag; 

    // The state data
    elT(&mArrRef)[rows][cols];
    int mCurrRow = 0;
    int mUserCol;

    // Copy all members.
    colIterT(const colIterT &rhs) = default;

    // Remember array and column choice.
    colIterT(elT(&arr)[rows][cols], int col)
        : mArrRef(arr),
          mUserCol(col),
          mCurrRow(0)
    {}

    colIterT &operator++()
    {
        ++mCurrRow;
        return *this;
    }

    // return element at position.
    elT &operator*() { return mArrRef[mCurrRow][mUserCol]; }

    // Compare all data members.
    bool operator!=(const colIterT &rhs) 
    { 
        return  &rhs.mArrRef != &mArrRef
            ||  rhs.mCurrRow != mCurrRow
            ||  rhs.mUserCol != mUserCol;
    }
    bool operator==(const colIterT &rhs)
    {
        return !(*this != rhs);
    }

    // row past last one.
    colIterT end()
    { 
        colIterT l(*this);
        l.mCurrRow = rows;
        return l;
    }

    // first row.
    colIterT first() 
    { 
        colIterT l(*this);
        l.mCurrRow = 0;
        return l;
    }
};

// freestanding function returning the begin
// iterator for a two-dimensional array.
// It is convenient that the type parameters can be deduced from the argument.
template <typename elT, size_t rows, size_t cols>
colIterT<rows, cols, elT> fst(elT(&arr)[rows][cols], int usrCol)
{
    return colIterT<rows, cols, elT>(arr, usrCol);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int arr[3][5] = {   { 0,  1,  2,  3,  4  }, 
                        { 10, 11, 12, 13, 14 }, 
                        { 20, 21, 22, 23, 24 } 
                    };

    cout << "Column with index 2: ";
    // Use type explicit template type name 
    colIterT<3, 5, int> colIter(arr, 2);
    for_each(colIter.first(), colIter.end(), [](int n){ cout << n << " ";  });

    cout << endl;

    cout << "Column with index 3: ";

    // Use convenience iterator functions, no explicit type name
    auto start = fst(arr, 3);
    auto end = start.end();
    for_each(start, end, [](int n){ cout << n << " ";  });

    return 0;
}
```

Sample session:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 -o iterTest iterTest.cpp  && ./iterTest
Column with index 2: 2 12 22
Column with index 3: 3 13 23
```